# PHP form sending blank email

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, email

I've create a php for my messages to be sent from the website to clients email. But once the email is sent i receive a blank email. I've tried using .$_post['name']. to call the field and i've tried .name.

I am using bootstrap to construct the form.

```
<form class="email" method="post" action="mailer.php">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter Your Telephone Number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="postcode">Post Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="Postcode">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="laptopmake">Make</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="laptopmake" name="laptopmake" placeholder="Enter Your Laptop Make(HP,Toshiba">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label for="laptopmodel">Model</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="laptopmodel" name="laptopmodel" placeholder="Enter Your Laptop Model Number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label for="faultdescription">Fault Description</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="faultdescription" name="faultdescription" placeholder="Describe Your Laptop Fault"></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                      Send Message
                </button>
               </div>
        </form>
```

This is the PHP mailer.

```
   <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
print_r($_POST)

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $laptopmake = $_POST['laptopmake'];
    $laptopmodel = $_POST['laptopmodel'];
    $faultdescription = $_POST ['faultdescription'];
    $message =$_POST['message'];



     $to = "aihsanm93@gmail.com";
    $subject="Laptop Repair Request!"; 
   $body = 'Name:' .$name. "\n\n"; 'Email:' .$email. "\n\n" ;'Postcode:'  .$postcode. "\n\n"; 'Message:' .$message . "\n\n";'Telephone:' .$telephone. "\n\n"; 'Laptop Make:' .$laptopmake. "\n\n"; 'Laptop Model:' .$laptopmodel. "\n\n";  'Fault Description:' .$faultdescription. "\n\n"; mail($to, $subject,$body, $from); 
    echo "Your Message has been sent"; 


    header('Location: index.html');
exit();


/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem=''){
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
{
show_error($problem);
}
return $data;
};

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
<html>
<body>

<p>Please correct the following error:</p>
<strong><?php echo $myError; ?></strong>
<p>Hit the back button and try again</p>

</body>
</html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Update version

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Add a `print_r($_POST)` to the top of the page to make sure you're getting the data you expect.

Comment: Remove the `isset` and enable `error_reporting`. Almost none of your form fields has a `name=`.

Comment: Off the top of my head, it looks like for some reason isset($_POST['submit'] is evaluating to false. Maybe that button needs an ID?

Comment: @mario nailed it - you must have a `name=` attribute on your form elements.

Comment: I don't see `$from` defined either.

Comment: @mario i've added name="fieldname"  also taken on isset and enabled error reporting and print_R I($_Post) 
and i get this error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) on line 6

Comment: Then fix your syntax errors. Nobody can guess what your code looks like now. (And it's off-topic generally.)

Comment: @mario i've updated the code. any help is appricated

Comment: Same mistake as thousands of other questions about `unexpected T_VARIABLE`.

Comment: @mario Well done you put it on hold... but it doesn't matter as i have solved the question myself. please change the the question to answered... thanks for all your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use " . " instead of " ; " for collect information.
Change line with starting " $body " to :

```
 $body = 'Name:' .$name. "\n\n" . 'Email:' .$email. "\n\n" . 'Postcode:'  .$postcode. "\n\n".  'Message:' .$message . "\n\n" . 'Telephone:' .$telephone. "\n\n" . 'Laptop Make:' .$laptopmake. "\n\n" . 'Laptop Model:' .$laptopmodel. "\n\n" .  'Fault Description:' .$faultdescription. "\n\n";
 mail($to, $subject,$body, $email);
```

Comment: Still blank. all  i receive is the field names not the values

Comment: Check the function "mail".